# How can I put my python code in startup in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wanted to put my python code in boot in raspberry pi.

I tried rc.local, ./bashrc but while booting program is working & I am using opencv + camera +voice command. That's not working in boot.

Please give me a way to run voice + camera + opencv  + python code in boot.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make it run as a service as mentioned in method 4 of following article:

https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

**Step 1– Create A Unit File**

Open a sample unit file using the command as shown below:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/sample.service
```

Add in the following text :

```
 [Unit]
 Description=My Sample Service
 After=multi-user.target

 [Service]
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/sample.py

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should save and exit the nano editor.

[image]

This defines a new service called “Sample Service” and we are requesting that it is launched once the multi-user environment is available. The “ExecStart” parameter is used to specify the command we want to run. The “Type” is set to “idle” to ensure that the ExecStart command is run only when everything else has loaded. Note that the paths are absolute and define the complete location of Python as well as the location of our Python script.

In order to store the script’s text output in a log file you can change the ExecStart line to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/sample.py > /home/pi/sample.log 2>&1
```

The permission on the unit file needs to be set to 644 :

```
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/sample.service
```

**Step 2 – Configure systemd**

Now the unit file has been defined we can tell systemd to start it during the boot sequence :

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable sample.service
```

Reboot the Pi and your custom service should run:

sudo reboot

[image]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I wanted to put voice means speech than camera also above method is not working for me. Any other wat to do it?